# Android Programmatically created content not displayed correctly

Tags: android

I'm trying to create some view programmatically. Here's what it should look alike :

[image: 1]!

This is what i have :

[image: 2]!

This is my layout :

```
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/choose_activity_dialog_table_layout">

                    <TableRow>
                            <!-- ACTIVITY TYPE -->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="0dip"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="left">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/pct_equitation_white"
                                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                                        />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Test"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <!-- ACTIVITY TYPE -->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="0dip"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/pct_amhe_white"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                                        />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Test"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <!-- ACTIVITY TYPE -->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_width="0dip"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_gravity="left"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                                        android:src="@drawable/pct_ecriture_white"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                                        />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Test"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                    </TableRow>


            </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my loop :

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_activity_dialog_view, container, false);

    int count = 1;
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
    TableLayout mainLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.choose_activity_dialog_table_layout);

    for(UserActivity ua : HomeActivity.userActivityStore.getUserActivities()){
        Activity currentActivity = HomeActivity.activityStore.findByActivityId(ua.getActivityId());

        if(currentActivity == null)
            continue;

        if(count % 3 == 0){

            count = 1;
            mainLayout.addView(row);
            row = new TableRow(v.getContext());

        }

        ImageView pictogramImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        final int pictogramImageViewWidth = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pictogramImageViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pictogramImageViewWidth, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        pictogramImageView.setLayoutParams(pictogramImageViewParams);
        pictogramImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        pictogramImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pct_amhe));

        TextView activityNameTextView = new TextView(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams activityNameLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        activityNameLayoutParams.setMargins(
                0,
                (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                0,
                0
        );

        activityNameTextView.setLayoutParams(activityNameLayoutParams);

        activityNameTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        activityNameTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        activityNameTextView.setText(currentActivity.getName());

        RelativeLayout rowRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        final int rowRelativeLayoutWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(rowRelativeLayoutWidth, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        rowRelativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        rowRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        rowRelativeLayout.addView(pictogramImageView);
        rowRelativeLayout.addView(activityNameTextView);
        row.addView(rowRelativeLayout, count - 1);

        count++;
    }

    mainLayout.addView(row);
```

I don't what's the problem in here, i've been looking for topics and stuff for hours and i just can't get it right..

Comment: The intended view could be easily layout using xml. Is there any reason you like to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up to inflate a layout and it's been way faster.

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_activity_dialog_view, container, false);

    int count = 1;
    TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
    TableLayout mainLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.choose_activity_dialog_table_layout);

    for(UserActivity ua : HomeActivity.userActivityStore.getUserActivities()){
        Activity currentActivity = HomeActivity.activityStore.findByActivityId(ua.getActivityId());

        if(currentActivity == null)
            continue;


        View chooseActivityView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_activity_item, (ViewGroup) row, false);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) chooseActivityView.findViewWithTag("relative_layout");
        row.addView(relativeLayout);

        if(count % 3 == 0){

            count = 0;
            mainLayout.addView(row);
            row = new TableRow(getContext());
        }

        count++;
```

My layout looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- ACTIVITY TYPE -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:tag="relative_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pct_amhe_white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd advise people looking for a solution to their problem that the second argument of inflate changes a lot about the render.